# External api tranlations: Models vs call endpoint, laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, rest

I have a question about the best way to handle a requirement in laravel specifically.

I have two projects:

1 - One in laravel which does certain things for a company daily matters.

2 - The other one in nodejs, is just an api for translations.

How do i load this translations into the laravel project.

**PLAN A AND B.**

**Plan A**: Through models, specifying the $connection variable (that points to another sql connection) in the model.An then using the models to query by the key of the translation.

**Plan B**: Ussing Guzzle to make a rest call to the express node api for getting all the translations for that language. And then storing it in an array and get them from there.

Note that if i do it calling to the api. I might have to call that endpoint in each service that wants to translate something.Im also getting all the translations and i might need just a couple of keys to translate.

Thank you , i hope it was clear, and im sure this question hasnt been asked before in such a concrete manner.

Comment: If it possible by plan A though Models is always better than calling API in each call

Comment: Okey, thank you. I did use models to do it in the end, since it is better in terms of performance and is more clean also.